# Add image at form submit

Tags: 7, forms, media

I have created a form that has a submit button.

```
$form['products_submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    "#id"  => "submit_first",
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => 'products_submit_driven_callback',
                'method' => 'replace',
                'effect' => 'fade',
                'progress' => array('type' => 'none'),
            ),
            '#prefix' => '<div class="button-logged-in">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>'
    );

  return $form;
```

And I want to add an image inside the button, at the left of 'Submit' text. I tried to add the img tag inside the t function but it just showed the code and not the image. Does anyone know how can I manage this?

Comment: seems to be answered here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13796/generating-button-type-submit-with-the-form-api

Comment: No, I have already tried that but it doesn't work, the button has no value

Answer (score -1):

You can handle this from CSS.

Like :

```
.button-logged-in.input{
    background-image: url(/images/buttons/submit.png);
}
```

Example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920076/html-css-how-to-add-image-icon-to-input-type-button