# Why I can't use the same code from Drupal 7 in Drupal 8 to generate a button with FAPI?

Tags: 8, forms

Following the question [Generating <button type="submit"> with the form API](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/13796/28275) for Drupal 7 I tried to implement the same thing in Drupal 8.

I need the following output:

```
<button type="submit" class="clearfix"><span>Login</span></button>
```

So I tried to use this code:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#prefix' => "<button type ='submit'>",
  '#suffix' => "</button>",
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => "<span>" . t('Login') . "</span>",
);
```

But I obtain this:

```
<span>Login</span>
```

But if I use this code:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#prefix' => "<b>",
  '#suffix' => "</b>",
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => "<span>" . t('Login') . "</span>",
);
```

I obtain this:

```
<b><span>Login</span></b>
```

So the `<button>` tag is eliminated but the `<b>` tag not. Very strange for me, the <kbd>Button</kbd> is not rendered.

Thanks to @Kevin I used the [leymannx answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/230031/28275) an with this code I solve the problem:

```
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'inline_template',
  '#template' => '<button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>',
];
```

But, why I can't use the same code in Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 to generate a button with FAPI?

Comment: Have you tried adding the span to your prefix and suffix? `"<b><span>"` ...  What's the point of the span anyways? are you trying to inline stuff?

Comment: Check that link for two potential solutions

Comment: @NoSssweat The front-end developper want this "<button type="submit" class="clearfix"><span>Login</span></button>" in the page, but if you use the code that works in Drupal 7 it doesn't works in Drupal 8.

Comment: @Kevin thanks, yes the leymannx answer (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/230031/28275) solve my problem, I will edit my question to see if we can find why this has changed.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer don't forget to up vote laymannx ;-)

Comment: @Kevin I changed the question.

Comment: @NoSssweat I changed the question

Comment: After that duplicate flag was raised, I edit the question and the new question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it is not working in Drupal 8 as in Drupal 7 is, that prefix and suffix are passed to [xssFilterAdminIfUnsafe()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/function/Renderer%3A%3AxssFilterAdminIfUnsafe/8.2.x) function in [doRender()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/function/Renderer%3A%3AdoRender/8.2.x) function. Thus preventing all tags except the tags specified in [$adminTags](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Xss.php/property/Xss%3A%3AadminTags/8.2.x).

Excerpt from doRender:

```
  // We store the resulting output in $elements['#markup'], to be consistent
  // with how render cached output gets stored. This ensures that placeholder
  // replacement logic gets the same data to work with, no matter if #cache is
  // disabled, #cache is enabled, there is a cache hit or miss.
  $prefix = isset($elements['#prefix']) ? $this->xssFilterAdminIfUnsafe($elements['#prefix']) : '';
  $suffix = isset($elements['#suffix']) ? $this->xssFilterAdminIfUnsafe($elements['#suffix']) : '';

  $elements['#markup'] = Markup::create($prefix . $elements['#children'] . $suffix);
```

You can use '#allowed_tags' property to enable specific tags. So this should work:

```
  $form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => "<button type ='submit'><span>" . t('Login') . "</span></button>",
  '#allowed_tags' => ['button', 'span'],  
  );
```

But '#allowed_tags' property will not work for '#prefix' and '#suffix'.